# AppiumOptions : System.TypeLoadException : 'Access is denied: 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities'.'

Tags: android, selenium, appium

The following code generates the error *"System.TypeLoadException : 'Access is denied: 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities'.'"* : [ScreenCap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLyLH.png)

```
             DriverOptions appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
            //var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "9");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption(MobileCapabilityType.NewCommandTimeout, 60);
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "emulator-5554");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption("appPackage", appPackage);
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalOption("appActivity", appActivity);

            var driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri(host), appiumOptions);
```

**Selenium version** : 4.0.0-alpha05

I didn't have this issue with the latest version of Selenium, but I have to use this one.
I also use the appium server.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it’s a bug in Appium. The Appium .NET bindings incorrectly attempt to use the Selenium `DesiredCapabilities` class as its base class for [`AppiumCapabilities`](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/blob/0aa5668b302c872171f927c79ffb5964dd4ec77f/src/Appium.Net/Appium/AppiumCapabilities.cs#L10). However, this class has been marked obsolete [since July, 2018](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/0b310c111486897cc7c711855ee9dc9005fc2dc3). The class was marked “internal” in [November, 2018](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/5bd9f79c9c236720bf08c6ed68fd9dc1a9f30fb0), removing its public visibility in Selenium 4.0 alpha 1. There are [open issues](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/issues/336) in the Appium issue tracker on refactoring this support, but it have not yet been acted on.

Comment: Than you very much for your explanation ! I've tried everything to fix it in my project, but it didn't work.

Comment: That’s the thing. You can’t fix it in your project; it must be fixed by Appium’s .NET project. Please feel free to accept this answer as correct, even though it’s not a solution. I would encourage you to engage with the Appium .NET bindings maintainers to encourage them to fix the issue on their side.

Comment: You're right ! I've created the topic on the official appium forum, but still no answer.